# Convert text to json using JsonPath

Tags: java, json, algorithm, jsonpath

I am given a csv file with lots of text and corresponding JsonPath notations .
Example :

```
Alfa,$.patients[1].name,String   
id-123,$.patients[1].id,String    
severe,$.patients[1].condition,String  
Beta,$.patients[2].name,String  
id-321,$.patients[2].id,String  
normal,$.patients[2].condition,String
```

I need to convert from text to Json object in Java .Can anyone suggest an algorithm or any existing library for this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a very simple json object:

Put the key value pairs in a map -

```
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String> ();
    map.put(KEY, VALUE);
```

Generate Json String

```
StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder("{");
for (Map.Entry < String, String > entry: map.entrySet()) {
    json.append(entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue()).append(",");
}
//removes the last "," which is unnecessary
json.deleteCharAt(json.lastIndexOf(","));
json.append("}");
return json.toString();
```

Try json-lib or Gson for more complex ones.

Comment: Thanks let me try using hashes .